# How to set figsize, labels and title with .plot()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame called `loss` and I am trying to plot it by doing the following way

`loss.plot()`

However I want the plot to be big. Thus I do this way

`plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))`

`loss.plot()`

But somehow it is not taking any effect on figsize. I am using jupyter notebook. Can someone help me?

**Edit 1**

I asked how to set labels and title also later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can either do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))
loss.plot(ax=ax)
```

Or

```
ax = loss.plot(figsize=(12,10))
```

For both option, you can modify `ax` before render:

```
ax.set_xlabel('This is X label')
ax.set_ylabel('That is Y label')
ax.set_title('The title')

# render
plt.show()
```